# Sitecore ISE powershell inconsistent results

Tags: powershell-extensions

I am running a script in Sitecore powershell to find items bases on a regular expression on a custom field ('Subkey'). This script sometimes shows results and sometimes shows 'No items available'.

Why is this not consistent? And how is this possible? I am running this within the Sitecore ISE

```ps
Write-Host "Begin script"

function Get-InvalidKeysAndSubkeys {
   #param([string]$label)
   Get-ChildItem  -Recurse | Where-Object { 
    (
     ((![string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_.Subkey)) -and ($_.Subkey -match "[^a-zA-Z0-9$ \-_\.!'()]"))       
     )
    }
  }
$x = Get-InvalidKeysAndSubkeys
$x | Show-ListView -Property Name,Key,SubKey,Id,ItemPath
Write-Host "End script"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out the problem was not having a

> -Language

parameter for the Get-ChildItem call. Sometimes it would be evaluated for the correct language and sometimes not. Forcing the language fixed the problem :)

Answer (score 5):

You are missing one important parameter (`-Path`) when invoking `Get-ChildItem`:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem  -Recurse
```

Fix this with something like this:

```powershell
Get-ChildItem -Path "/sitecore/content" -Recurse
```

If you do not define `-Path` parameter your context item (start item for getting children) will be taken from item defined here

[image]

Comment: I am using the Context setting. So a Path parameter is not needed?

Comment: Yes. I assumed that different Context item was your main problem thus I shared a different approach to invoke Get-ChildItem. Are you able to reproduce unwanted behavior while using `-Path` parameter as well?

Comment: In the event that you choose not to use the `-Path` parameter, you can put `Set-Location` at the top of your script. I don't recommend this approach but would get the job done when running the script in multiple contexts (i.e. ISE, Console, Context Menu).